# Can I take powershell's existence for granted on windows boxes from scheduled tasks?

Tags: windows, powershell

Are there any scenarios in which powershell may be disabled or crippled by admins?
I'd like my MSI to install a scheduled task that runs a custom powershell script on startup.
Not worried about the ExecutionPolicy, I can work around it.
My worry is that there might be some edge case (some enterprise policy or whatever) in which this won't work. Thoughts?
Targetting: windows server 2008/R2, 2012/R2, 2016/R2, 2019 and windows 10.

Comment: `Are there any scenarios in which powershell may be disabled or crippled by admins?` - Yes. `My worry is that there might be some edge case (some enterprise policy or whatever) in which this won't work. Thoughts?` - You can't assume that Powershell hasn't been disabled in any particular environment.

Comment: `I'd like my MSI to install a scheduled task that runs a custom powershell script on startup.` What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: A MSFT app is messing up the registry on startup. My scheduled task is triggered on an event and fixes the registry